# Is convolution useful on a network with a timestep of 1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

This code comes from https://www.kaggle.com/dkaraflos/1-geomean-nn-and-6featlgbm-2-259-private-lb, The goal of this competition is to use seismic signals to predict the timing of laboratory earthquakes. The person in this link has won first place among more than 4000 teams

```
def get_model():
   inp = Input(shape=(1,train_sample.shape[1]))
   x = BatchNormalization()(inp)
   x = LSTM(128,return_sequences=True)(x) # LSTM as first layer performed better than Dense.
   x = Convolution1D(128, (2),activation='relu', padding="same")(x)
   x = Convolution1D(84, (2),activation='relu', padding="same")(x)
   x = Convolution1D(64, (2),activation='relu', padding="same")(x)

   x = Flatten()(x)

   x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
   x = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)

   #outputs
   ttf = Dense(1, activation='relu',name='regressor')(x) # Time to Failure
   tsf = Dense(1)(x) # Time Since Failure
   classifier = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x) # Binary for TTF<0.5 seconds

   model = models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=[ttf,tsf,classifier])    
   opt = optimizers.Nadam(lr=0.008)

   # We are fitting to 3 targets simultaneously: Time to Failure (TTF), Time Since Failure (TSF), and Binary for TTF<0.5 seconds
   # We weight the model to optimize heavily for TTF
   # Optimizing for TSF and Binary TTF<0.5 helps to reduce overfitting, and helps for generalization.
   model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=['mae','mae','binary_crossentropy'],loss_weights=[8,1,1],metrics=['mae'])
   return model
```

[image]

However, According to my derivation, I think `x = Convolution1D(128, (2),activation='relu', padding="same")(x)` and `x = Dense(128, activation='relu ')(x)` has the same effect, because the convolution kernel performs convolution on the sequence with a time step of 1. In principle, it is very similar to the fully connected layer. Why use conv1D here instead of directly using the fullly connection layer? Is my derivation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Assuming you would input a sequence to the LSTM (the normal use case):**

It would not be the same since the LSTM returns a sequence (`return_sequences=True`), thereby not reducing the input dimensionality. The output shape is therefore `(Batch, Sequence, Hid)`. This is being fed to the `Convolution1D` layer which performs convolution on the `Sequence` dimension, i.e. on `(Sequence, Hid)`. So in effect, the purpose of the 1D Convolutions is to extract local 1D subsequences/patches after the LSTM.

If we had `return_sequences=False`, the LSTM would return the final state `h_t`. To ensure the same behavior as a Dense layer, you need a fully connected convolutional layer, i.e. a kernel size of `Sequence` length, and we need as many filters as we have `Hid` in the output shape. This would then make the 1D Convolution equivalent to a Dense layer.

**2) Assuming you do not input a sequence to the LSTM (your example):**

- In your example, the LSTM is used as a replacement for a Dense layer.
  It serves the same function, though it gives you a slightly different
  result as the gates do additional transformations (even though we
  have no sequence).
- Since the Convolution is then performed on `(Sequence, Hid)` = `(1, Hid)`, it is indeed operating per timestep. Since we have 128 inputs and 128 filters, it is fully connected and the kernel size is large enough to operate on the single element. This meets the above defined criteria for a 1D Convolution to be equivalent to a Dense layer, so you're correct.

As a side note, this type of architecture is something you would typically get with a [Neural Architecture Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_architecture_search). The "replacements" used here are not really commonplace and not generally guaranteed to be better than the more established counterparts. In a lot of cases, using Reinforcement Learning or Evolutionary Algorithms can however yield slightly better accuracy using "untraditional" solutions since very small performance gains can just happen by chance and don't have to necessarily reflect back on the usefulness of the architecture.

Comment: Note that the input shape only has a single time step, so the "sequence" really isn't a sequence at all.

Comment: @xdurch0 Yikes, what a monstrosity. Oversaw that completely as I didn't expect someone to use an LSTM on a non-sequence. Thanks, will update.